# How to hide standard (existing) HtmlHelper

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-2, html-helper, asp.net-mvc-3

I have created a set of custom HtmlHelper extensions.

I would like to know if it is possible to prevent other developers in the same project from using the standard HtmlHelpers.

Eg: Say, I have..

```
public static string CustomDropDown(this HtmlHelper html)
{
   //Custom code here
}
```

I want only `<% Html.CustomDropDown(..)%>` to be visible to developers and not the standard `<% Html.DropDownList(..)%>` or any of its overloads.

Anybody having any clue if this is possible and how?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Consider using EditorTemplates and/or DisplayTemplates instead. 
This way, all your developers need to do is to always call the

```
Html.EditorFor(model => model.MySpecialProperty);
```

or

```
Html.DisplayFor(model => model.MySpecialProperty);
```

Answer (score 1):

Why not just tell them?

"Hey guys, these custom helpers are a lot better and you should use them".

If you have management support this shouldn't be a problem.

Answer (score 0):

I doubt there is any failsafe solution and maybe it's not a very wise thing to do either...

But you could consider taking out the

```
<add namespace="System.Web.Mvc" />
```

section out of the  in the web.config.

Comment: ...and watch as your solution fails to compile. Oops. A little too radical, methinks.

Comment: Hmmm, I've seen somebody suggest the EditorVisible() attribute on classes, but just cant seem to find that post again on stackoverflow. Was thinking it somehow has something to do here..

Comment: Shouldn't fail to compile with skipping that line. At most maybe failing at runtime...

Comment: I did try this before I posted this question. Not satisfactory, I must say, since I still want other things in System.Web.Mvc to be accessible.

Answer (score 0):

ASP.NET MVC is an open project - you can download source code and manually remove some methods from HtmlHelper class, rebuild and supply this library to your developers.

Comment: That was my first impulse. :) But I want to target only specific parts of the solution.

Answer (score 0):

Could you not just refactor your code??

```
public class CustomControls
{
    private readonly HtmlHelper _helper;
    public CustomControls(HtmlHelper helper)
    {
       _helper = helper;

    }

    public static string DropDown()
    {
       //Custom code here
    }
 }

 public CustomControls CustomControls(this HtmlHelper helper)
 {
    return new CustomControls(helper);
 }
```

Usage:

```
<%:  Html.CustomControls().DropDown()  %>
```

Comment: But that doesn't affect the visibilty or usage of  Html.DropDownList, does it?

Comment: No, but the assumption was you only wanted developers to see a list of your extensions instead of a complete list (where others may have created control of the same name).